# Pandas how to make a transpose of data-frame to get values for the remaining two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Have a df with values

```
name    marks    subject

mark     50       math
mark     75       french
tom      25       english
tom      30       Art
luca     100      math
luca     100      art
```

How to make a transpose of a dataframe so it looks like this

```
name math art french english

mark  50        75  
tom        30         25
luca  100  100
```

tried:

`df.T` and  `df[['marks','subject']].T`

but

Answer (score 0):

This is a pivot.  First we need to normalize the subject column, then we pivot.

```
df['subject'] = df['subject'].str.lower()
df.pivot(index='name', columns='subject', values='marks')
```

See here for more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot